# Custom logic in foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with different numbers of secondary arrays that need to be custom merged. I dont think there is a function that can help. I hoped recursive merges would do the trick but in this case they append rather than merge (mismatched/numeric indexes). So I think it needs a specific foreach loop and some logic. Its the logic I am struggling to get my head round : some really tricky logic.  Here is the challenge:

```
                $array1=
                    Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 8
                                [1] => 300
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 9
                                [1] => 400
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 10
                                [1] => 500
                            ) 
                    }

            $array2=
                Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8
                            [1] => A
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 9
                            [1] => B
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                            [1] => C
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11
                            [1] => D
                        )       
                }

            $combined=
                Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8
                            [1] => 300
                            [2] => A
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 9
                            [1] => 400
                            [2] => B
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                            [1] => 500
                            [2] => C
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 11
                            [1] => 0 (there was no sub array value so it resolves to zero)
                            [2]=> D
                        )       
                }
```

Sub Array[0] is the month. There will alway be two sub elements in each of the two input $arrays ie month and a parameter (eg sales volumes-$array1 and  brand-$array2). And there will always be 3 sub elements in the $combined sub array (month/sales volume/brand). In each sub array there will always be a value for the month. But there may not be a value for one of the associated sub array elements. And inb this case it should resolve to zero. See example. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two loops (just draft - writting on phone)

```
$res = [];
foreach($array1 as $i) {
   $res[$i[0]] = [ $i[0], $i[1], ''];
}

foreach($array2 as $i) {
   if (! isset($res[$i[0]])) {
       $res[$i[0]] = [ $i[0], 0, ''];
   }
   $res[$i[0]][2] = $i[1];
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/908819)

result will be with indexes as  "id". To reset them `$res = array_values($res);`

Comment: @splashsh58 thank you. That suggestion takes a bit of getting your head around. If it works its damned clever!

Comment: @WChris i think, it must :)

Comment: Had  go. There is a php error inthere somewhere. Will have a look and see if I can find out why

Comment: It was just your if statement, Fixed that bu the array is coming out like this example peice of it   [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 500
                )

            [1] => 8
            [2] => 
        )

Comment: I think on the right road with this approach. I am just messing with the logic and trying to get it to format correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Took a few hours but its now working perfectly. The concept of two arrays did it - although I needed to rework the answer quite a bit. Happy to post the answer if you are interested. Marked you up for your help. Again thanks Splash58

Comment: *Took a few hours*  it's horribly :( I've updated the answer with working demo

Comment: It took a few hours only because i was making it work in a very specific way - inside my application - and then extend it more broadly. Your concept worked fine and I learnt a shed load. It just needed a bit more work sir. So again thank you hugely.

Comment: You won that one hands-down Splash :)  Brilliant. Accepted answer

Comment: :))) Glad that can help.

Comment: May i just ask a quickie about your demo code please? Ive not seen the use of an IF statement without the { } before. So my inclination was to put the { } in - thinking it was a mistake and wouldnt work without them. But the code fails when I do that. What is going on there Splash?

Comment: @WChris Due to php syntax without  curly braces only 1st statement will be executed as it is wrapped by braces - that is about `if`, `else`, `while`,..

Comment: I've changed that in the answer because it's a bad practice

Comment: Well I really didnt know that, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use array_map with a custom function

```
function combineSalesArrays($array1, $array2) {
    return(array(((empty($array1[0])) ? $array2[0] : $array1[0]),((empty($array1[1])) ? 0 : $array1[1]),((empty($array2[1])) ? 0 : $array2[1])));
}
print_r(array_map('combineSalesArrays', $array1, $array2));
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 300
            [2] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 400
            [2] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 500
            [2] => C
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 0
            [2] => D
        )

)
```

Comment: Ah I only just got this. Thank you miknik!!!  I had been working on Splash' approach for the last two hours before your post - and all is now working perfectly albeit a lot of changes required.